# Code not Working For Large Permutations

Tags: java

I've just completed a codility test and only achieved a score of 81%. My code failed when a 'large permutation' was tested against it.

I've got no idea why this failed, as the spec says all values are integers, and my for loop uses only int values. I would really appreciate it if somebody could look at my code and tell me why it provides a value of -1 for massive permutations:-

https://codility.com/demo/results/demo4G8CJS-9YN/

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8

                int target = X;
        int[] path = new int[X];


       for(int i = 0; i < A.length-1; i++) {
           if(A[i] != path[A[i]-1]) {
           path[(A[i]-1)] = A[i];
           target--;
           }

           if(target==0) {
               return i;
           }

       }
          return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does "large" mean larger than 2^31?

Comment: try putting int counter = ( A.length -1) , cuz every time this loop happens this number gets calculated again

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing code. Perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this.

Comment: @vlatkozelka Many thanks for your suggestion, that will definitely improve the performance!

Comment: @Chris This question involves a quirk in the processing of Java code, not just a code review. I've posted it on code review just now anyway

Comment: Yeah, don't move it to code review - they'll close it there, because you're trying to find a bug.  Stack Overflow is the right place for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)(not i < A.length - 1). As of now, the last element of the array is just ignored. It actually fails a very simple test: an array of one element and X = 1.

Comment: This answer should be correct. The linked Codility test results even show, that the test "single/single element" fails.